# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in this in Joomla 3

Tags: php, view, joomla

I have a Joomla 3 application.

My View looks like this:

```
class XYViewCacheMngt extends JViewLegacy{

/**
* @return void
*/
function display($tpl = null)
{
    JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_( 'Cache Managemet' ), 'generic.png' );
    JToolBarHelper::deleteList();
    JToolBarHelper::back();

    $items = $this->get('Items');

    // Check for errors.
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
    {
        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }

    $this->assignRef("items",  $this->createTable($items));

    // Display the template
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

In my default.php I now want to access $this

```
  <?php
    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );


if($this->items == null){
    return;
} 

JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.multiselect');

?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=...&view=cachemngt'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
    <div class="col100">
    <?php 
    echo $this->items;
    ?>
    </div>
    <input name="controller" type="hidden" value="cachemngt" />
    <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
</form>
```

When I do so, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

But, if I do print_r($this) I get the correct result => A dump of a XYViewCacheMngt object.

Can somebody help me how I can fix this?

Regards,
TJ

Comment: To answer your question, it would make sense to see your entire default.php

Comment: Added the full default.php

Comment: Where are you doing the `print-r` and is the error happening at the first `$this`?

Comment: I did the print_r($this) before if($this->items == null)